# mysql Error:13 MyISAM table file not found

Tags: c#, mysql, exception, file-not-found, loaddata

I have a set of files (around 20MB each) that needs to be inserted into a table in mysql. The insert is done in a loop for all files (single threaded). This works usually fine, but from time to time I am getting the following exception: `File '.table.MYD' not found (Errcode: 13)` for one file in the middle of the set (the first 50 ran ok, next 2-3 will fail and then the following will run fine again). If I just re-run the queries for the failed files in mysql workbench (or re-run the failed ones), they are working fine. The table is just created, with no indexes - so problems like 'index failed', table fragmentation or any other problems should not be there.

Below is the complete stacktrace:

```
File '.dbtable.MYD' not found (Errcode: 13)
----------------------------------
 at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
 at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int32& insertedId)
 at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
 at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
 at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
 at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
 at Utils.SqlUtils.ExecMysql(String sql, String connection)
 at Utils.MySqlExecQueue.DoExec(Object data)
----------------------------------
MySql.Data
```

where:
+ `ExecMysql` - looks like

```
using (MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(connection))
{
  cnn.Open();

  using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, cnn))
  {
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```

+`DoExec` is a method that pics the files from a queue, creates the sql statement and calls `ExecMysql` above.
+the inserting code and mysql are on the same machine (Windows 2008, x64);
+there are no antiviruses or any other tool running on that machine that may lock the table file (as found on some blogs);
+the c# (.net 4) code is using mysql connector 6.5.4, the mysql version is 5.5;

I have implemented a dummy workaround like 'try-to-insert-while-13error-exception-is-thrown' but I have a strong feeling that this is not the correct solution.

Any ideea what is going on and how to fix this issue once and for all?

**UPDATE** - Clearly, the 'try-to-insert-while-13error-exception-is-thrown' fix is not a good ideea: I just got the same exception while running a SELECT on the table right after succesfully inserted data.

**UPDATE 2** - checked the logs and I have noticed another wierd exception: `Error on rename of '.\db\table.MYD' to '.\db\#sql2-4e4-1677.MYD' (Errcode: 17)` ... things are getting better ...

Answer (score 0):

do you have any anti-virus? If so make sure the mysql directory and its temp folder are excluded from AV and try again.

Comment: No, there's no antivirus on that machine.